# Tenant option is missing in "Admin" Dashboard of Camunda Web App, How to enable it?

Tags: multi-tenant, camunda

In Camunda Web app, on opening Admin menu, its noticed that there are options such as Users, Groups,System and Authorization whereas Tenant option is missing.
Any idea what's wrong? or How to enable it?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: camunda BPM v7.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this feature is only available starting at version 7.5.x of Camunda BPM platform. You can check the release notes here https://blog.camunda.org/post/2016/05/camunda-bpm-750-released/. It would be great if you would upgrade and try again.

Cheers,
Askar

Comment: but even in user guide of v7.4 [Camunda 7.4 Multi tenancy](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/process-engine/multi-tenancy/) is mentioned , was that a primitive feature then? what's the difference?

Comment: As you can extract from the blog post which is linked by Askar the following is the difference: `In addition to the existing approach with one process engine per tenant that separates data into different database schemas, you can now employ a single process engine for all tenants. It reduces the effort to manage large tenant bases significantly.`